showDialog rebuild after navigating
I am trying to show a loading after making a request and immediately after trying to navigate to another page. For this I am using a ShowDialog and a FutureProgressDialog. The problem is that when the showDialog finishes executing and I navigate to another page, the showDialog builder is executed again, causing the request to be called twice. Could you explain to me what is happening here and how it could be solved. Thank you so much
Here I show you where I use the showDialog and the method I call. I have tried nivagtion in other ways but I always have the same result. However, if I simply do not navigate, the showDialog builder is only called once as I would like it to be. I also tried with the useRootNavigator property set to false and nothing
onPressed: () async {
 await showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder:(context){
  return FutureProgressDialog(
          sendAttendanceRequest(context),
          progress: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
          opacity: 0.7,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
          ),
         );
  }
 )
 context.pushReplacementNamed(SCREENS.attendances.toName);
}

Future sendAttendanceRequest(BuildContext context) async{
try {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('${Server.baseURL}/api/v1/attendance/request'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': prefs.getString('token') ?? ""
      },
      body: jsonEncode(
          {
            "type_request": _attendanceId == "" ? "create": "edit", //"create" or "edit"
            "attendance_id": _attendanceId,
            "description": _descriptionController.text,
            "project_id": _selectedProjectId,
            "started_at": _combineDateTime(_clockInDate, _clockInTime),
            "ended_at": _combineDateTime(_clockOutDate, _clockOutTime)
          }
      ),
    );
 }
}


I think that you should make a Navigator.pop() before you navigate to the screen to get out from the show dialogue
Navigator.pop()
context.pushReplacementNamed(SCREENS.attendances.toName);
